# Belongs To Many with pimary key relation returns null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, primary-key, relation

In my app I want to have a relation between addons and products, where a product can have many addons,

I've created a `addons table`, `product table` and `addon_product` table to save both `ids`,

Have defined the relations in the models and even gone as far as to create a model `addonsProducts` to insert the keys in my `controller`

I want the addons to be shown in my Api `resources` response when I call my products.

**Addon Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Addon extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','price', 'icon', 'description'];
    protected $table = 'addon_products';

      public function products()
     {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
     }
}
```

**Addon Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Addons extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('addons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('price');
            $table->string('icon');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });    
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('addons');
    }
}
```

**Product Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{

  protected $fillable = ['name','brand', 'type', 'icon', 'price', 'description'];
// protected $table = 'products';

  public function stores()
 {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Store::class);
 }
  public function orders()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class);
  }
  public function addons()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Addon::class);
    }

}
```

**Product Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
      Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('icon');
            $table->string('brand');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->string('price');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

**addonProduct Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AddonProducts extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['addon_id','product_ids', 'active'];
    //protected $table = 'addon_product';

      public function products()
     {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
     }
     public function addons()
     {
      return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

**addonProduct Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddonProduct extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('addon_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('addon_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('active')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('addon_product');
    }
}
```

**Product resource**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ProductResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
      return [
     'id' => $this->id,
     'productname' => $this->productname,
     'icon' => $this->icon,
     'brand' => $this->brand,
     'type' => $this->type,
     'price' => $this->price,
     'addons' => $this->addon,
     'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at,
     'updated_at' => (string) $this->updated_at,

   ];
    }
}
```

**Addon resource**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class AddonResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'price' => $this->price,
            'icon' => $this->icon,
          ];
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a $fillable product_ids in AddonProducts model, is that a typo?

Comment: @dparoli Yes a typo

Comment: `$protected $table = 'addon_products`' in Addon model should be `protected $table = 'addons'`

Comment: there is no need for `addonProduct` Model the keys can be set automatically, please read documentation.

Comment: This code makes no sense. What should a column named `product_ids` save? multiple ids? Why are you creating JsonResources instead of using `protected $hidden` to hide certain properties from `toArray()` functionality? Why Would you create an `addonsProducts` model when it looks like a many-to-many relation and you can just use that laravel feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to declare the table in the class `Addon`, or declare it correctly and add the pivot field `active`.

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Addon extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','price', 'icon', 'description'];
    protected $table = 'addons';

      public function products()
     {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('active');
     }
}
```

In the `Product` class, declare the relation as `belongsToMany` too.

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','brand', 'type', 'icon', 'price', 'description'];

    public function stores()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Store::class);
    }

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class);
    }

    public function addons()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Addon::class)->withPivot('active');
    }
}
```

You dont need to declare the class `AddonProduct` since it represents a liaison table.

now you can simply do:

```php
$products = Product::with('addons')->get();
```

You can also run a condition on the `active` field.

```php
$products = Product::with(['addons' => function($addon) {
    $addon->where('pivot.active', '=', 1);
}->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried your answer, but it does not show the addon that's bound to the product, but the relation. 

`id: 1,
addon_id: 1,
product_id: 1,
active: 1,
created_at: null,
updated_at: null`

Comment: Yes I did change the table